# How to describe unmistakable similarity in two Andrew Lloyd Webber songs?

Tags: melody, composers, musical-theatre

So, I'm a *very* elementary music student with a theatrical background, and I want to ask a professor about what I hear as a very marked similarity between a couple of songs from different Andrew Lloyd Webber musicals:

- [Then We Are Decided](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FRIl97V4KV4), *Jesus Christ Superstar* (Caiphas' vocal line)
- [She Is A Diamond](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JlEofxOm1j8), *Evita* (Perón's vocal line)

Unfortunately, I don't yet have the ear training or perhaps even the vocabulary yet to describe what it is I'm hearing, and I don't want to sound stupid. Is it just a very similar melody and rhythm? *Is* it a very similar melody and rhythm? Is there a better way to describe what the similarities, and/or for vocabulary for when a composer's work seems to sometimes have a "trademark sound" like this?

I appreciate any and all help.

Comment: I think you can just ask the professor. Mention that they sound very similar to you and ask them if they know why that is. Composers (even much-vaunted ones like Beethoven and Tchaikovsky) often subconsciously or deliberately re-use ideas and themes and melodies, etc. It's not unusual or surprising.